# What is affect of RMA on Order

Tags: magento2, dashboard, rma, order-management, returns

I am new to RMA so i have some questions for which i could not find answers on other articles.

1. Order on which customer initiates RMA, does it's amount calculated on dashboard sales statistics?
2. If customer return/replace order item, does it update existing order or create new order?
3. What's status of order for which RMA initiated/approved?

I also referred some RMA extension guides but could not find any satisfactory answers.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Yes, amout will be deducted as it will consider as cancel order.
> 2. it will cancel the current one and create a new one.
> 3. Canceled - depends on RMA extension if it is providing new status.

NOTE: further it's depends on the flow of RMA extension,

are you using magento commerce?

Comment: I am using magento community version

Comment: ok, please accept the asnwer if it is correct

Comment: Yes i will. In case of partial return(i.e. returning one item from multiple order items), will it cancel whole current order?

Comment: "it will cancel the current one and create a new one". what will be new order status? Processing? and in case of rejection from admin for RMA request, how it will be managed?

Comment: It should be processing because customer already paid for order. if admin reject the request the current order status will not change, once admin approve it then current order status will change.